# Convert Class Object to JSON Python - EasyPost - Django

Tags: python, json, django, class, object

I am building a JsonResponse view in Django 1.7 via Python 2.7.9 for tracking requests made through the EasyPost API. The view:

```
def TrackingTable(request, trackingnumber):
    easypost.api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

    tracker = easypost.Tracker.create(
          tracking_code='EZ3000000003',
          carrier="UPS"
      )

    tracking = tracker['tracking_details']

    return JsonResponse({"tracking":tracking, "url":request.get_full_path})
```

When this wasn't working I tried to see if the issue was related to Json.  So i went in manually and tried to pull out JSON values since the EasyPost API (and response object) shows JSON as the output:

```
easypost.api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

tracker = easypost.Tracker.create(
      tracking_code='EZ3000000003',
      carrier="UPS"
  )


>>> tracker
<Tracker Tracker at 0x7f467982be50> JSON: {
  "api_key": "IAiiSCSBtBXPKiaVmcc1wQ", 
  "carrier": "UPS", 
  "created_at": "2015-03-18T15:48:43Z", 
  "est_delivery_date": "2014-08-27T00:00:00Z", 
  "id": "trk_qufcxYmC", 
  "mode": "test", 
  "object": "Tracker", 
  "shipment_id": null, 
  "signed_by": null, 
  "status": "out_for_delivery", 
  "tracking_code": "EZ3000000003", 
  "tracking_details": [
    {
      "api_key": "IAiiSCSBtBXPKiaVmcc1wQ", 
      "datetime": "2014-08-21T14:24:00Z", 
      "message": "BILLING INFORMATION RECEIVED", 
      "object": "TrackingDetail", 
      "status": "pre_transit", 
      "tracking_location": {
        "api_key": "IAiiSCSBtBXPKiaVmcc1wQ", 
        "city": null, 
        "country": null, 
        "object": "TrackingLocation", 
        "state": null, 
        "zip": null
      }
    }, 
    {
      "api_key": "IAiiSCSBtBXPKiaVmcc1wQ", 
      "datetime": "2014-08-21T14:48:00Z", 
      "message": "ORIGIN SCAN", 
      "object": "TrackingDetail", 
      "status": "in_transit", 
      "tracking_location": {
        "api_key": "IAiiSCSBtBXPKiaVmcc1wQ", 
        "city": "SOUTH SAN FRANCISCO", 
        "country": "US", 
        "object": "TrackingLocation", 
        "state": "CA", 
        "zip": null
      }
    }, 
    {
      "api_key": "IAiiSCSBtBXPKiaVmcc1wQ", 
      "datetime": "2014-08-22T08:51:00Z", 
      "message": "DEPARTURE SCAN", 
      "object": "TrackingDetail", 
      "status": "in_transit", 
      "tracking_location": {
        "api_key": "IAiiSCSBtBXPKiaVmcc1wQ", 
        "city": "SOUTH SAN FRANCISCO", 
        "country": "US", 
        "object": "TrackingLocation", 
        "state": "CA", 
        "zip": null
      }
    }, 
    {
      "api_key": "IAiiSCSBtBXPKiaVmcc1wQ", 
      "datetime": "2014-08-23T09:31:00Z", 
      "message": "ARRIVAL SCAN", 
      "object": "TrackingDetail", 
      "status": "in_transit", 
      "tracking_location": {
        "api_key": "IAiiSCSBtBXPKiaVmcc1wQ", 
        "city": "SAN FRANCISCO", 
        "country": "US", 
        "object": "TrackingLocation", 
        "state": "CA", 
        "zip": null
      }
    }, 
    {
      "api_key": "IAiiSCSBtBXPKiaVmcc1wQ", 
      "datetime": "2014-08-24T08:10:00Z", 
      "message": "OUT FOR DELIVERY", 
      "object": "TrackingDetail", 
      "status": "out_for_delivery", 
      "tracking_location": {
        "api_key": "IAiiSCSBtBXPKiaVmcc1wQ", 
        "city": "SAN FRANCISCO", 
        "country": "US", 
        "object": "TrackingLocation", 
        "state": "CA", 
        "zip": null
      }
    }
  ], 
  "updated_at": "2015-03-18T15:48:43Z", 
  "weight": 17.6
}>
```

"`tracker`" is a class object

```
>>> print type(tracker)  
<class 'easypost.Tracker'>
```

Attempt to convert class to dicitonary:

```
>>> this = dict(tracker) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easypost/__init__.py", line 359, in keys
    return self._values.keys()
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Attempt to dump to JSON:

```
>>> json.dumps(tracker)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <Tracker Tracker at 0x7f467982be50> JSON: {
  "api_key": "IAiiSCSBtBXPKiaVmcc1wQ", 
  "carrier": "UPS", 
  "created_at": "2015-03-18T15:48:43Z", 
  "est_delivery_date": "2014-08-27T00:00:00Z", 
  "id": "trk_qufcxYmC", 
  "mode": "test", 
  "object": "Tracker", 
  "shipment_id": null, 
  "signed_by": null, 
  "status": "out_for_delivery", 
  "tracking_code": "EZ3000000003", 
  "tracking_details": [
    {
      "api_key": "IAiiSCSBtBXPKiaVmcc1wQ", 
      "datetime": "2014-08-21T14:24:00Z", 
      "message": "BILLING INFORMATION RECEIVED", 
      "object": "TrackingDetail", 
      "status": "pre_transit", 
      "tracking_location": {
        "api_key": "IAiiSCSBtBXPKiaVmcc1wQ", 
        "city": null, 
        "country": null, 
        "object": "TrackingLocation", 
        "state": null, 
        "zip": null
      }
    }, 
# Removed same data as above to make shorter
  "updated_at": "2015-03-18T15:48:43Z", 
  "weight": 17.6
} is not JSON serializable
>>>
```

It looks like the nested JSON in "`tracking_details`" is causing errors to be thrown, any help on how to convert the data into a JSON Object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the source](https://github.com/EasyPost/easypost-python/blob/master/easypost/__init__.py#L429), you can call tracker.to_dict()

The `to_dict()` method is available on all EasyPost objects in the client.

> Example:
> `tracker.to_dict()`.

Comment: It is the right answer, no workaround needed to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 2):

So the quickest way I have been able to solve this has beeb via [jsonpickle](https://jsonpickle.github.io/).

Example from jsonpickle:

```
import jsonpickle

frozen = jsonpickle.encode(obj)
Use jsonpickle to recreate a Python object from a JSON string:

thawed = jsonpickle.decode(frozen)
Warning Loading a JSON string from an untrusted source represents a potential security vulnerability. jsonpickle makes no attempt to sanitize the input.
The new object has the same type and data, but essentially is now a copy of the original.

assert obj.name == thawed.name
If you will never need to load (regenerate the Python class from JSON), you can pass in the keyword unpicklable=False to prevent extra information from being added to JSON:

oneway = jsonpickle.encode(obj, unpicklable=False)
result = jsonpickle.decode(oneway)
assert obj.name == result['name'] == 'Awesome'
```

Applied to this situation:

```
>>>tracker_encode = jsonpickle.encode(tracker, unpicklable=False)
>>>tracker_decoded= jsonpickle.decode(tracker_encode)
>>> print type(tracker_decoded)
<type 'dict'>
>>> for x in tracker_decoded:
...     print x
... 
status
object
weight
tracking_details
shipment_id
created_at
_immutable_values
_transient_values
updated_at
_unsaved_values
tracking_code
carrier
mode
_values
est_delivery_date
_retrieve_params
api_key
id
signed_by
```

This encoded the entire output to a dictionary that I am then able to convert to json using the `return JsonResponse({"tracking":tracking_decoded, "url":request.get_full_path})`

Result using [Postman](https://github.com/a85/POSTMan-Chrome-Extension/wiki):
[image: Postman]

Comment: Not needed workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a Serializer!

Check marshmallow at http://marshmallow.readthedocs.org !

I've been using this to JSON serialize my objects!

You will need to write something like:

```
SomeObjectSerializer(Schema):
    class Meta:
      fields = ('api_key', 'id', 'someotherattributes')
```

and then when you want to serialize your objects just call:

```
obj = Model(**args)
SomeObjectSerializer(obj).data
```

and this should be giving you a JSON serialized output